# Actor-Critic in Discrete action spaces

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/reinforcement-learning-w-keras-openai-actor-critic-models-f084612cfd69) and am trying to use it for another OpenAI Gym environment (MountainCar-v0). This environment has a discrete action space instead of a box one. By this I mean if you were to print(env.action_space) for this particular environment you get Discrete(3) as the result as opposed to some Box(3,) action space.

Here is the code:

```
def create_critic_model(self):
    state_input = Input(shape=self.env.observation_space.shape)
    state_h1 = Dense(24, activation='relu')(state_input)
    state_h2 = Dense(48)(state_h1)

    action_input = Input(shape=self.env.action_space.shape)
    action_h1    = Dense(48)(action_input)

    merged    = Add()([state_h2, action_h1])
    merged_h1 = Dense(24, activation='relu')(merged)
    output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(merged_h1)
    model  = Model(input=[state_input,action_input], 
        output=output)

    adam  = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam)
    return state_input, action_input, model
```

As you can see, the critic model takes in both the state and action as input. Because I am working in with a discrete action space I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Discrete' object has no attribute 'shape'`. This is because the discrete action space has no shape but I have to pass it through as an input. And when just passing env.action_space as the input, I get this error: `TypeError: 'Discrete' object is not iterable`

The Critic model uses an action input which is the action space shape. Being a discrete action space, [mountaincar](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCar-v0/) does not have an action space shape. How would I reconfigure this code to suit my purpose(use action input for a discrete action shape space).

Also, on this line:

```
future_reward = self.target_critic_model.predict([new_state, target_action])[0][0]
```

it seems we are trying to predict on 2 diff arrays, and I get an error regarding that. So what's going on there?

Error is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[-0.47361678, -0.00322982]]), array([[ 0.00318837, -0.05581997,  0.06615788]], dtype=float32)].
```

**UPDATE**

So after switching to my new machine, installing fresh python, keras, tensorflow, and gym(which got rid of the other error) I am left with a new keras error:

```
AssertionError: Please provide to Input either a `shape` or a `batch_shape` argument. Note that `shape` does not include the batch dimension.
```

Also still getting the array related error.

Comment: Add more details (more code).  Digging through links to find what you are referencing isn't ideal.

Comment: According to [the code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/discrete.py), `Discrete` does have a `shape` property just like [`box`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/box.py)...

Comment: Running this code `import gym


env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')
print(env.action_space.shape)`

gives this error:

`AttributeError: 'Discrete' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: Doing exactly the same I get no error

Comment: What version of gym? and your environment? running pip show gym I get: 
`Name: gym
Version: 0.9.2
Summary: The OpenAI Gym: A toolkit for developing and comparing your reinforcement learning agents.
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/gym
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: gym@openai.com
License: UNKNOWN`

Comment: With gym 0.9.4 (installed with `pip install gym`) it gives no error, either with Python 2 or 3.

Comment: It seems [this commit from August](https://github.com/openai/gym/commit/d54f4e62eeaf0c4c4b2687c1c0b5664c2622317a#diff-a5b46f3fbe92ca4207f3dfb21bd66f8b) is where `shape` was added to `Discrete`.

Comment: Have you had any progress on suiting the code that was for continuous action spaces to discrete action spaces? I had a question that is confusing me as given below. I would be appreciated if you share your results here as well. As far as I understand the output of the actor-network is an array of probabilities-like values corresponding to each action in action space. Shouldn't you need to get the action with the biggest probability to select the best action before feeding it to env.step(action)?

Comment: Mine was an issue of conflicting gym versions. Want to link me to your issue?